# comparing a number with a variable in shell if command

Tags: shell, if-statement, comparison

I have a variable that I am storing as

```
upstream_introngap=$(awk '$3==$start-1 && $4 ~/$geneid/' File | awk '{print $3-$2}')
```

and using it in the code as

```
if [ "$upstream_introngap" -lt "100" ] ; then
    condition
```

However I am getting an error

```
[: : integer expression expected
```

I am trying different combinations but I am unable to get the right comparison expression, is the problem here the variable or the expression/number that is being compared with?
For instance

```
grep -w ENSG00000007237:I2 File
chr17   9964697 10017758    ENSG00000007237:I2  -
awk '$3==10017758 && $4 ~ /ENSG00000007237/' File | awk '{print $3-$2}' for 
53061
```

the above line
I want to compare this number (53061) to see if it's less than 100

Comment: Use `set -x` before running this code, and see what the actual comparison it's running is. Most likely the value of your variable isn't what you think.

Comment: ...or it's, say, a floating-point value, not an integer (to which bash's built-in math support is limited). If you need to do floating-point math, why not do it in awk, since your data is from there?

Comment: Show your sample input and clarify what you're trying to do as there might be better ways to do this.

Comment: It is the awk code that is not working as you would like.  Provide us with enough information that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The awk code contains `$start` and `$geneid` but neither `start` nor `geneid` is defined in the awk code.  That likely means that the OP was hoping that shell would substitute for those variables but it won't because the awk code is in single-quotes.  Whatever he expects that awk code to be doing, it seems highly unlikely to me that it is doing it.

Comment: Ahh -- yup, that's solid reasoning. Should probably be something like `awk -v start="$start" -v geneid="$geneid" '$3 == (start - 1) && $4 ~ geneid { print $3 - $2 }'`, or similar.

Comment: hi @John1024 'she' has uploaded an instance now

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni, your first line of code is using `$start` and `$geneid` inside single quotes, so they aren't actually getting replaced with actual values by the shell before `awk` is started. Consequently, even if `start=10017759` and `geneid=ENSG00000007237`, you won't get the same behavior between `awk '$3==$start-1 && $4 ~/$geneid/'` and `awk '$3==10017758 && $4 ~ /ENSG00000007237/' `. This is what my proposed modification to the awk code, above, was intended to address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
start=10017759
geneid=ENSG00000007237
upstream_introngap=$(awk -v s="$start" -v id="$geneid" '$3==s-1 && $4~id {print $3-$2; exit}' File)
if [ "$upstream_introngap" -lt "100" ]; then
    echo less than
else
    echo greater or equal
fi
```

With this as the sample file:

```
$ cat File
chr17   9964697 10017758    ENSG00000007237:I2  -
```

The script produces this output:

```
$ bash script
greater or equal
```

Notes:

1. `start` and `geneid` are *shell* variables.  The options `-v s="$start"` and `-v id="$geneid"` assign those shell variables to *awk* variables.
2. There is no need for two awk commands.  A single command can select the line and perform the subtraction.
3. The expression `$4~id` is true if the fourth field matches `id`.  In this context, `id` is treated as a regular expression.  If `id` contains any regex-active characters, such as `()*+[]`, the results may not be what you expect.